# Why does compiling a specific c++ sourcefile with g++ give different results on a PC and a mac?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, makefile

I've compiled and linked some c++ sourcefiles with make on a PC, with no errors. Then I used the same sourecefiles and the same makefile and tried it on a mac, but got 6 errors. The compiler should be the same and interpreit the files in the same way, but obviously not? Can it be the LLVM-g++ that is used in mac that is different from g++ on the PC?

All errors have this path: /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h

g++ version 4.6.1 (PC) and Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) on mac

one error is:

```
usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:129:35: error: no type
  named 'value_type' in 'std::pair<int, int>'
  typedef typename _Iterator::value_type        value_type;
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Show the source code that you are compiling, and show the compiler version, the compilation commands and the error messages. We cannot help without all of them.

Comment: LLVM/g++ is different from g++ and you also need to consider the versions. g++ 4.2.x is quite different from g++ 4.8.x. Just run `g++ --version` on each machine.

Comment: Did you used any specific libs such as windows.h, dos.h? Are you satisfied additional dependencies of third-party libs?

Comment: All errors have this path: /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h  g++ version 4.6.1 (PC) and Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn) on mac

Comment: File `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h` is internal and specific to the libstdc++ provided by GCC 4.2.1; you should not include it when compiling with LLVM or with G++ 4.6!

Comment: If you use two different compilers it is always possible to get different results also on the same system with the same Makefile. Why you think that *make* will change the results or why you think that the same make will give you the same result? And also consider the versions of each compiler. Different versions could also result in different behavior.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. But can one find two compiler settings on two different platforms so that every source code are compiled with the same output?

Answer (score 2):

Using the same source code and makefiles will not necessarily produce the same behaviors on different platforms. Here are some things that could result in differences:

- The makefiles may do platform specific things.
- Source code may use preprocessor to distinguish platforms.
- Compilers and compiler versions may interpert the source differently

  - May support different features and extensions
  - May have different bugs
  - May require different arguments
- The platform libraries may differ.

  - Platform specific libraries won't be available on other platforms
  - Different standard library implementations may have different extensions/bugs.
  - Different standard library implementations may target different specification versions (e.g., C++03 vs. C++11 libraries).
  - Using the library in a way that results in undefined or implementation defined behavior can have different results between different implementations.
  - 'portable' but not standardized libraries may differ (e.g., functions taking `char *` vs. `char const *`

---

From the error you posted "error: no type named 'value_type' in 'std::pair'" I would guess that you're using the standard library incorrectly and that one of the standard library implementations you're using let you get away with it but the other isn't.

It seems that at some point in your code you're instantiating a template with template arguments that don't fit the requirements, and so somewhere deep inside the template instantiation an error occurs. As part of that error message the compiler should be giving you a list of the template instantiations that lead to it. You need to follow that trace back to your code to see what template you're using incorrectly.